# Unowned property not captured in async block

Tags: swift, swift3

I am working with code which is structured like this snippet (this needs Swift 3):

```
import Dispatch

var processing = false

class Customer {
    var card: CreditCard!
    var name: String!

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func createCard() -> CreditCard {
        card = CreditCard(customer: self)
        return card
    }

    func check() {
    }
}

class CreditCard {
    unowned let customer: Customer //if not "unowned" a reference cycle will result
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global() //needs Swift 3 to compile

    init(customer: Customer) {
        self.customer = customer
    }

    private func doBackgroundCheck() {
        self.customer.check()
    }

    func process() {
        queue.async {
            //self.customer is no captured
            self.doBackgroundCheck()
            print("processed")
            processing = false
        }
    }  
}

func issueCard(to name: String) {
    let c = Customer(name: name)
    let card = c.createCard()
    processing = true
    card.process()
}


//main
issueCard(to: "Tom")
while processing {
    sleep(1)
}
```

This code crashes, because the unowned property "customer" is not captured in the async block. The customer object gets deallocated before the async block can run. Making "customer" a strong reference works but it can cause a reference cycle leading to a leak.

I wasn't able to find any guidance on such code patterns in the Apple documentation. Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Comment: Making  it a `weak` reference is one possible option.

Comment: Thanks. But that will only mean "customer" will be made nil on deallocation and I can check for nil before accessing. I need "self.customer" captured in the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture a strong reference to `self.customer` using
a "capture list" in the closure:

```
func process() {
    queue.async { [customer = self.customer] in
        customer.check()
        print("processed")
        processing = false
    }
}
```

Inside the closure, `customer` is a strong reference to `self.customer`,
which exists until the closure has been executed. This causes a
*temporary* retain cycle, but not a *permanent* one, because the
closure is executed eventually.